# Docker + OpenResty - flexible configuration. How to?

Tags: docker, nginx, deployment, lua, openresty

I have the openresty application that deploys with docker.

My docker file:

```
FROM openresty/openresty:alpine-fat

ARG APPLICATION_PATH="/srv/www/my-app"

COPY nginx.conf /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf

RUN mkdir ${APPLICATION_PATH}
```

I'm running docker with this command:

```
docker run -v $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY):/srv/www/my-app -v $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)/conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d --name="$(APP_NAME)" -p $(PORT):80 -d $(CONTAINER_NAME)
```

This command stored in the `Makefile` and variables values like that:

```
CONTAINER_NAME = my-app
APP_NAME = my-app

override PORT = 8080

ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
    CURRENT_DIRECTORY=%cd%
else
    CURRENT_DIRECTORY=${PWD}
endif
```

So also I have `my-app.conf` stored in the `conf` directory. This is nginx-configuration file, where I have this line:

`content_by_lua_file '/srv/www/my-app/main.lua';`

And further I have `nginx.conf`, where I have this line:

`lua_package_path ";;/srv/www/my-app/?.lua;/srv/www/my-app/application/?.lua";`

I don't want duplicate `/srv/www/my-app` in the 3 files. How I can avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, your approach is not consistent.

You copy nginx.conf file, but mount a volume for my-app.conf (is it included into nginx.conf?)

Curiously that `$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)/conf` is mounted twice - as `/srv/www/my-app/conf` and as `/etc/nginx/conf.d`.

Below is my approach for OpenResty containers:

1. Write simple nginx.conf without includes. Copy it into container as you do.
   The only reason to mount a folder with nginx.conf is ability to reload nginx configuration after changes. Keep in mind - if you would mount a single file reload may not work. https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/328
2. Copy all Lua files mentioned in *_by_lua_file directives into `/usr/local/openresty/nginx`
3. Copy all Lua files required from files above (if any) into `/usr/local/openresty/lualib`
4. Don't use absolute file paths in *_by_lua_file directives, you may specify relative path to `/usr/local/openresty/nginx`
5. Don't use lua_package_path directive, defaults should works.

Here is the simple working example https://gist.github.com/altexy/8f8e08fd13cda25ca47418ab4061ce1b

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have revised my approach with you pieces of advice, now all looks pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this repo
https://github.com/RezaImany/openresty-full-solution.git
it has docker compose file and you can easily modify the nginx.conf and other .conf files

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35187865)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).